# T-SQL surprising DATALENGTH values of char and nchar

Tags: t-sql, unicode, char, datalength

```
SELECT DATALENGTH('źźźź')                       -- 4
SELECT DATALENGTH(CONVERT(char, 'źźźź'))        -- 30
SELECT DATALENGTH(CONVERT(nchar, 'źźźź'))       -- 60
SELECT DATALENGTH(CONVERT(varchar, 'źźźź'))     -- 4
SELECT DATALENGTH(CONVERT(nvarchar, 'źźźź'))    -- 8
```

I know that char is non-Unicode type, but nchar actually IS a unicode type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - and what's your question?

If you don't define a **length** in a `CAST` or `CONVERT`, then **30 characters** is the system-default.

So this

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(CONVERT(char, 'źźźź'))
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(CONVERT(char(30), 'źźźź'))
```

and since the `CHAR` (and `NCHAR`) datatypes are **always** padded to their defined length, you get 30 characters and thus 30 (`char`) and 60 (`nchar`) bytes length.

All perfectly clear and well documented - see [MSDN documentation on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

> *length*
>
> *Is an optional integer that specifies the length of the target data type. The **default value is 30**.*

When you're using the variable length strings instead `varchar` or `nvarchar`, you only get as many characters stored as there are really in the string - therefore you get 4 characters and thus 4 and 8 bytes of length.